# What is the state of the art in labour-automation data-exchange?

Tags: interface, standards, serial-communication

I just came across ASTM E1394-97 "Transferring Information Between Clinical Instruments and Computer Systems", because a supplier offers a system supporting this standard.
It looks rather pre-DOS age. I wonder, if labour-automation lives in stone-age ignoring XML, JSON, etc.

Moreover, ASTM E1394-97 seems to be withdrown, and I wonder wat should we use for a new implementation.

Thank you for any insights!

Answer (score 7):

After diving deeper in labour-automation and LIS-interfacing I've found out that  ASTM E1394 based protocols are still in use.
ASTM E1381/1394 were replaced by LIS2-A1 / LIS01-A2
A more modern approach seems to be HL7 but it seems to be not widely used.

I've found useful these links for implementing my LIS connector:

- http://www.hendricksongroup.com/code_003.aspx - Checksum calculation
- http://www.afinion.net/sites/default/files/adcc%20datasheet.pdf - Just another description **EDIT: Broken**
- http://code.google.com/p/python-astm/ - ASTM implementation in python
- http://www.linkedin.com/groups/ASTM-E-1394-97-standard-2069898.S.160152562 - LinkedIn group

**EDIT**

I've implemented an ASTM-client for a new machine and a middleware as a proxy for a couple of some older machines using the original sandard, the third link (pythin astm) and some reference-docs from Abbott. A good help the first time was a pretty old but working tool from Roche. Than I've writen my own tool and used it. Some of the work can be found here, but they are in pretty unmature state. Finally I couldn't maintain both the public and customer's tools and gave the public tools up.

- https://github.com/vheinitz/ASTMViewer
- https://github.com/vheinitz/GoodnightAstm
- https://github.com/vheinitz/culist

Comment: E1381 is the low level communications protocol, and E1394 is the high level protocol. LIS1 is a revision of the former ASTM E1381-02, and LIS2 is a revision of the former ASTM E1394-97.

Comment: The 2nd link is broken and the rest are not an informative source about the protocol.

Comment: @uri Thanks fo the broken hint. Actually using the 3rd link I've implemented the first version of my client. There are data structures defining all fields of astm 1394.

Comment: @ValentinHeinitz thanks for the quick response.
Am I missing something about the 3rd link? It seems to be source code only. No descriptive information. Or are you referring to the comments in the code?

Answer (score 2):

There is a new standard under development by the IHE (Integrating the Healthcare Enterprise) and the IICC (IVD Industry Connectivity Consortium) that is planned to supersede LIS01-A2 and LIS02-A2. The messages are based on HL7 v2.5.1 and it uses the MLLP as the transport.

http://www.ihe.net/uploadedFiles/Documents/Laboratory/IHE_LAB_Suppl_LAW.pdf - The current revision of the IHE LAW Profile

http://www.ihe.net/technical_frameworks/#laboratory - IHE Laboratory Technical Framework

http://wiki.ihe.net/index.php?title=Laboratory_Analytical_Workflow - Wiki for the working group that is developing the standard